# Probability of having a path of a given length in a random graph

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, graph-theory, random-graphs

Suppose $G=\langle V,E \rangle$ is a directed graph consisting of $n\in \mathbb{N}$ vertices. Vertex $v_i \in V$ has an edge to vertex $v_j \in V$ with a probability of $P(i, j) = f(|i-j|)$ where $f$ is a descending "good enough" function.

What is probability to have a path of length $k$?

**Update 1.**
Let us consider a simplified problem. Suppose the probability of having an edge between any two arbitrary vertices is fixed and equals $p$. Thus, the adjacency matrix $\bf A$ consists of elements $a_{ij} = \delta(p)$ equal $1$ with a probability of $p$.

It's well known that $({\bf A}^k)_{ij}$ gives the number of $k$-paths from $v_i$ to $v_j$. Can we employ that?

Comment: It is not exactly clear how arcs are distributed. Is it for a $fixed$ acyclic digraph $G$, each arc of $G$ is deleted with probability $1-P(i,j)$? Or do you not mean to include the term acyclic?

Comment: @DPoole OK, let's remove the acyclicity requirement as irrelevant.

Comment: A few more questions. Do you want to know the probability that the digraph has a path of length $k$ or for some generic $v_i$ and $v_j$, the probability that there is a path of length $k$ between $v_i$ and $v_j$? Also are you looking for the exact probability or are asymptotic bounds for this probability sufficient? If asymptotic bounds are good, what range of $k$ and $p$ are you looking at?

Comment: @DPoole 1) the probability that the digraph has a path of length $k$. 2) exact probability (nevertheless, an example of asymptotic estimation will be useful)

Comment: In the limit for large graphs, the result you are looking for is Theorem 2.1 of  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.4104v1.pdf